# Materializecss; modal showing buttons from body

Tags: html, modal-dialog, materialize

I am trying to create a "casino" for a school project (my last project). I am using Materializecss to show a modal. And use javascript to show something else for every button clicked.

I have searched around trying to find a solution. But I don't really know how to format my question. So here is a image; [image]
As you can see, it shows 2 buttons where you can choose for tails or heads through the modal.

Modal code;

```html
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 id="header"></h4>
      <div id="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Button that triggers the modal;

```html
<li><a onclick="loginmodal();" class="btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Login</a></li>
```

And the javascript;

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
 });

function loginmodal() {
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Login";
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Login stuff here<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
}
```

It shouldn't show the buttons through the modal. As it is doing at the moment. The buttons are clickable, and when the form shows up, it just shouldn't be there.

Comment: I still need a answer...

Comment: What styling do the buttons have?

Comment: @ikkuh `<button id="tails" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="bettails();" style="background: rgb(66, 66, 66);">Tails</button>`